# Passing multiple parameters in the URL with flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters in the url but only one argument is accepting. I used the url curl -i http://localhost:5000/details_page/api/v1.0/recommendation?content_id=SINGTEL_movie_22937&category=details_page but only `content_id` is getting passed.

```
@app.route('/details_page/api/v1.0/recommendation', methods=['GET'])
def recommendation():
    category = request.args.get('category')
    content_id = request.args.get('content_id')
    print(content_id)
    print(category)
    return(content_id,category)
    if (category !='details_page'):
        abort(404)
    contents = cl.details_page(content_id)#goes to my logic
    return(jsonify({'content_id':contents}), 201)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I had problem with with my url. When using curl, the url should be within double quotes.

```
curl -i http://"localhost:5000/details_page/api/v1.0/recommendation?content_id=SINGTEL_movie_22937&category=details_page"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a small change in your code that you are returning two variables in a API thats why its no printing whether you have to pass it  as string or in a JSON format

## String

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/details_page/api/v1.0/recommendation', methods=['GET'])
def recommendation():
    category = request.args.get('category')
    content_id = request.args.get('content_id')
    print(content_id)
    print(category)
    return "{},{}".format(category, content_id)#changed this line
    if (category !='details_page'):
        abort(404)
    contents = cl.details_page(content_id)#goes to my logic
    return(jsonify({'content_id':contents}), 201)
#from app import app
```

## Dictionary

```
@app.route('/details_page/api/v1.0/recommendation', methods=['GET'])
def recommendation():
    category = request.args.get('category')
    content_id = request.args.get('content_id')
    print(content_id)
    print(category)
    return jsonify(
                category= category,
                content_id= content_id
           ), 200
    if (category !='details_page'):
        abort(404)
    contents = cl.details_page(content_id)#goes to my logic
    return(jsonify({'content_id':contents}), 201)
#from app import app
```

Comment: I got the output. We need to use double quotes in the url when we are using curl. That was the problem. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: yup you are right but in case of flask if content type is set to json then your must jsonify the return you can't return two variable so in your case you are putting url in string so its return string